# Getting more user information with Google API other then just the email and the googleID/Sub

Tags: php, oauth, google-api-client

I have my `setScopes()` method to `setScopes('email')`... I'm not sure how to grab more user information such as user profile images, names, etc etc. I'm wondering how to go about doing this. I've read the documentation, and it's not saying anything about how to generate the user information in the Payload.

My code is in PHP, please respond in that syntax. Not sure if you need more information other then this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are adding a scope, go to the [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google API's](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#plusv1) page.

There you will find a list of Scopes. To add a scope simple call the `addScope()` method when needed, and pass in the scope. You can add more then one scope. See example below which grabs the users information and email as well as profile information as well. (This assumes you're inside of a class with the Google Client saved to the `_client` variable.

```
$this->_client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
$this->_client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
```